# A 1D quantum harmonic oscillator with an additional degree of freedom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I was given a Hamiltonian and asked to find the energy levels. I've managed to find the alpha parameter by using the fact that H is hermitian. Afterwards I tried to express an eigenstate as a superposition of regular eigenstates (ones from a Hamiltonian that doesn't have this color operator in it) and the color states and it gave a result but it feels wrong to me and also I can't think of a way to extract information about degeneracies from that result.

I would be really grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong or missing. Thanks a lot! :)

[image: a screenshot of my work]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $[H,A]=0$ and so, these two operators can be simultaneously diagonalized. Now consider the eigenvalues and eigenstates of $A$. You have to compute
$$
  [|g\rangle\langle g|+i\alpha|g\rangle\langle b|-i\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}|b\rangle\langle g|+3|b\rangle\langle b|]|\chi\rangle=\lambda|\chi\rangle.
$$
This is a two-state operator and you can look for solutions in the form
$$
   |\chi\rangle =a|b\rangle+b|g\rangle
$$
with $a$ and $b$ two coefficients to be computed. Put this into the equation above and obtain
$$
  a(i\alpha|g\rangle+3|b\rangle)+b(|g\rangle-i\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}|b\rangle)=
\lambda(a|b\rangle+b|g\rangle) 
$$
giving the equations for the coefficients
$$
   i\alpha a+b(1-\lambda)=0
$$
and
$$
  (3-\lambda)a-i\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}b=0.
$$
With $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ this yields $\lambda_1=1/2$ and $\lambda_2=7/2$.

Now, the generic eigenstate of your Hamiltonian has the form $|n;k\rangle=|n;\lambda_k\rangle|\chi_k\rangle$ with $n$ spanning the states of harmonic oscillator and $k=1,2$. This will yields
$$
   E_{n,k}=H|n;k\rangle=\left[\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2A\right]|n;\lambda_k\rangle|\chi_k\rangle=
\left[\frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2\lambda_k\right]|n;\lambda_k\rangle|\chi_k\rangle
$$
and finally
$$
   E_{n,k}=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega\sqrt{\lambda_k}.
$$

Comment: Could you please explain the last part again? I lost you after "Now, the generic eigenstate...". Did you define the common eigenstate vector as a multiplication of two kets? Also you wrote that E = H|n;k> where the left hand side is a scalar and the right hand side is a vector. I suppose it's some sort of short hand notation but it confuses me, please, if you can, explain this part in more detail. And thanks a lot for your effort :)

Comment: Yes. This is due to the fact that $A$ and $H$ commute. So, I can write the generic eigenstate as the product of an eigenstate of the harmonic oscillator (taking into account that it should depend also on $\lambda_k$) and $A$. You can see that this choice is correct as this is indeed an eigenstate of the original problem.

Comment: Why is the \lambda_k under a root?

Comment: Because it enters linearly in the Hamiltonian with the product $\omega^2\lambda_k$ and so, to obtain the frequency straight you have to take the square root. This gives the proper energy spectrum.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that such an energy spectrum means that there are no degeneracies? That is, for each combination of possible n,k the energies will get unique values?

Comment: Yes, that's right.